# Remove TransactionScopeRequired = true

Tags: wcf, attributes, transactionscope, operation-contract

I have an operation contract, on a windows service and it has an attribute

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
```

I would like to get rid of this attribute. Reason :

> containerize the service.
>   and Containerized apps do not support MSDTC , that's the purpose of the attribute!

What are the implications of doing this? 
I can confirm the code within the operation contract inserts into a single database.
No events triggered, however I am unsure of whether there is a transaction where the service is consumed.

Can I get some advice on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service is requiring a transaction.

Only you can know whether this is necessary, we cannot check your service and database to check.

Please be aware that this enables not only *local* transactions, but -depending on binding- also enables *distributed transactions*. [See here for details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.servicemodel.operationbehaviorattribute.transactionscoperequired(v=vs.110).aspx).

You new system does not seem to support this (MSDTC is the Distributed Transaction Controller from MS). Again, whether this is a problem when you move over to this system is nothing we could find out. You will have to have a look at the system architecture and see whether this is something that was included "just because" and can be deleted without replacement, or if it's a key feature of your system that you need to keep.

Comment: I cannot see a TransactionFlow attribute which implies a new transaction is created and then committed when this operation contract is called. I am leaning towards getting rid of this even if the call is invoked from within a transaction scope by an external application.

Comment: If it's just used to save on three lines doing a local transaction manually, you could as well delete it and create a transactionscope manually in every method.